# Can Next.js be used with WordPress in multisite mode?

Tags: wordpress, next.js

Can Next.js be used with WordPress in multisite mode?

Specifically, we have WordPress with network sites installed as subdomains.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work with multi-site WordPress setup, but you'll also need to setup a node server if you want Server-Side-Rendering.

Suppose you have a domain `example.com` and you want visitors to go at `site1.example.com` and `site2.example.com`, to visit respective website.

In that case you'll have host your next.js site at those subDomains and some other subDomain for wordpress ex- `site1wp.example.com` and `site2wp.example.com`.

The next.js will access the data by making API request to something like `site1wp.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Let me know if that helpful by up-voting my answer, also if your use-case is different let me know.

Comment: Thanks AviKKi. Do you mean we need a next.js install for each subdomain site?

Comment: No you can just point all the subDomains to a single installation(server). You will have to code next.js to request the corresponding wordpress subDomain for the requests.

Comment: Thanks. I may need help with this in the future.

Comment: If you need any further assistance or want to hire someone ping me at atul7555 [at] gmail.com